# Equivalent months_between function for HiveQL

Tags: hive, datediff, netezza

I'm trying to use HIVE to calcuate the months between two dates that are years and sometimes decades apart.  In Netezza I used: `months_between(this_month('Date_1'),this_month(Date_2))` 
I am trying to translate to HIVE and don't think there is an existing date function that does this or a UDF available.  Has anyone tried to stagger existing HIVE commands to accomplish the same goal?

Answer (score 1):

This has been fixed in the latest version of Hive (1.2.0) where "months_between" is available.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-9518